# How can i update my database column name from laravel 5.3 artisan

Tags: database, updates, laravel-5.3

i tried with this 
php artisan make:migration update_username_field_to_users_table

but it didn't work and give an error.Let me now about the process i should follow.

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are getting

Comment: I forgot the exact one but it might ask to add something in the vendor or it could not find update library.

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel Docs

> Modifying Columns
>
> Prerequisites
>
> Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency
>   to your composer.json file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to
>   determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries
>   needed to make the specified adjustments to the column:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

> Updating Column Attributes
>
> The change method allows you to modify some existing column types to a
>   new type or modify the column's attributes. For example, you may wish
>   to increase the size of a string column. To see the  change method in
>   action, let's increase the size of the name column from 25 to 50:

```
 Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
     $table->string('name', 50)->change(); });
```

> We could also modify a column to be nullable:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
     $table->string('name', 50)->nullable()->change(); });
```

if this docs not working for you please provide the errors